# Paypalhere integration iOS

Tags: ios, heroku, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have an app that accepts payment via card swipe. I read and try to implement **PayPalHere SDK** in **iOS**. As per their documentation It requires to create **PayPal-retail-node** or you can call it's **rest API service** for login into PayPal.

I created that on **Heroku** by using following link  https://github.com/paypal/paypal-retail-node.

Everything works perfectly till deployment. you can check image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktGOD.jpg

But when I click any one of that link I got this message https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpJUm.jpg.

So please help me how can I set **redirect_uri** or **return_url** in PayPal developer account and what will I set in **APP_REDIRECT_URL** in following link

https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?button-url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpaypal%2Fpaypal-retail-node&template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fpaypal%2Fpaypal-retail-node.git.

It works perfectly in the example provided in PaypalHere SDK **TakePayments**.